# Converting string array into an object with the inner most child to be an empty array in JavaScript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I convert string array into an object except for the last string element in the array has have to have a value array?

```
const ArrayPath = ["UNIVERSAL HIP", "STEM", "BFX"]
```

should return

```
{ 
  "Universal Hip": {
    "Stem": {
      "BFX": []
          }
     }
}
```

This is what I have tried

```
let arrayPath = ["UH", "STEM", "BFX"]
let obj = {}
const helper = (obj, arrayPath) => {

  if (arrayPath.length === 0) {
    return obj
  }
  
  obj[arrayPath[0]] = helper(obj[arrayPath[0]], arrayPath.slice(1))
  if (arrayPath.length === 1) {
    return {
      [arrayPath[0]]: []
    }
  } else {
    return obj
  }
}

console.log(helper(obj, helper))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Using `Array.reduceRight`, you can get the result you want.
  It will loop from the last index to the first index and will run the callback.
  Now, on callback, it returns new object `{ [cur]: acc }`.

Here, `acc` is accumulator. And `cur` stores the current value. So it will be first - `BFX`, second - `UNIVERSAL HIP`, last - `STEM`.
And `{ [cur]: acc }` means to create new object with key(`cur` variable value) and value (`acc` variable value).

- So first case, if `cur = BFX`, acc will be `{ BFX: [] }`
- And second case, if `cur = UNIVERSAL HIP`, acc will be `{ UNIVERSAL HIP: previous acc }` so `{UNIVERSAL HIP: { BFX: [] }}`.

It will loop to the first item like this.

```js
const arrayPath = [ "UNIVERSAL HIP", "STEM", "BFX" ];

const output = arrayPath.reduceRight((acc, cur) => ({ [cur]: acc }), []);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: You could actually skip reversing and just [reduce-right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) e.g. `arrayPath.reduceRight((acc, cur) => ({ [cur]: acc }), [])` It's been available as long as `reduce` has existed.